# How to use TEXTJOIN with a row delimiter?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I use `=TEXTJOIN` to get all values from an array. `TextJoin` has a possibility to set a delimiter - but this delimiter is set after every value.

How is it possible to insert a delimiter after each row? Like this: if I use `TEXTJOIN` for an array `A2:B10`, so I want to insert a delimiter after value `B3`, `B4`, `B5` and so on. So if the delimiter is a |, I would get values `A2 B2 | A3 B3 | A4 B4 | ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it meet your requirement?

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,A2:A10&B2:B10))
```

[image]